# Is it Possible to Migrate or at Least Export Dropbox's Selective Sync Settings?

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox, migration

When setting up Dropbox on a new Windows computer, is it possible to migrate the selective sync settings from the old computer?

And if those settings can't be migrated and must be reapplied manually, then is there at least some way to export a list of the folders that were excluded via selective sync on the old computer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying over the files that keep the local Dropbox settings, which are located at the local "appdata" directory, i.e. here: `%APPDATA%\..\Local\Dropbox\` (see [this](http://forensicartifacts.com/2011/07/dropbox-config-files-windows/) for more information).

The files themselves seem to be encrypted SQL databases, so I doubt you'll be able to view or change them just for the selective sync settings, but you could try copying **everything** over and then changing the settings you don't like back to what they were.

Just be sure to back your existing files up before making the replacement (and, of course, exit the Dropbox application and every other process it may have open before doing this).